# Golang byte vs string

Tags: go

I'm trying to find a common element between two strings of equal length in Golang.

The element is found, but the string representation seems to include the byte value too. How can I get rid of it?

```
func main() {
    println(fmt.Printf("common element = %s",
        findCommonElement("abcdefghi", "ijklmnopq")))
}

func findCommonElement(firstElements, secondElements string) string {
    elementsInFirstGroup := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, charValue := range firstElements {
        elementsInFirstGroup[string(charValue)] = true
    }
    for index := range firstElements {
        if _, ok := elementsInFirstGroup[string(secondElements[index])]; ok {
            matchingElem := secondElements[index]
            println(string(matchingElem))
            return string(matchingElem)
        }
    }

    panicMessage := fmt.Sprintf("Could not find a common item between %s and %s", firstElements, secondElements)
    panic(panicMessage)
}
```

The output I get is

```
i
common element = i18 (0x0,0x0)
```

Code available [here](https://go.dev/play/p/rddy370aall)

Comment: What is `println` doing in that code (twice)?! See what you get without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt@go1.19.3#Sprintf) instead of `fmt.Printf`.

And avoid using the builtin [`println`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.19.3#println), instead use [`fmt.Println`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt@go1.19.3#Println).

---

https://pkg.go.dev/fmt@go1.19.3#Printf

```golang
func Printf(format string, a ...any) (n int, err error)
```

> Printf formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard output. It **returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.**

Hence the `18 (0x0,0x0)`...

- `18` is the number of characters in the string `"common element = i"`.
- `(0x0,0x0)` is the `nil` error value as printed by `println`.

---

More importantly however, your algorithm is flawed because it is mixing up bytes with runes. When you `range` over a string, the iteration variable `charValue` will be assigned a `rune`, which may be multi-byte. However when you index a string (e.g., `secondElements[index]`) the result of that is always a single `byte`. So panics or gibberish (invalid bytes) will inevitably be the result of your function. See [example](https://go.dev/play/p/d78B_aq8pnP).

You may get better results doing something like the following:

```golang
func findCommonElement(firstElements, secondElements string) string {
    second := map[rune]bool{}
    for _, r := range secondElements {
        second[r] = true
    }

    for _, r := range firstElements {
        if second[r] {
            fmt.Println(string(r))
            return string(r)
        }
    }

    panic("...")
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kNotThOrehj

Comment: I agree with what you said. Be aware that your algorithm is O(n^2) though

Comment: @MaPi then does [this one](https://go.dev/play/p/kNotThOrehj) work better for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Quite nice